# 2D Platformer Collision Detection/Resolution

Tags: java, game, collision

I am working on a 2D tile based platformer and was hoping to get someone to review my collision detection. I've only included the X collision check since the Y is essentially the same. Any suggestions/criticisms are appreciated.

```java
    // Corrects X movement if a collision occurs.
    private void checkXCollision()
    {
        // Find the range of tiles the player intersects
        Point topLeft = new Point(((int)(xtemp + dx) - collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize(), ((int)ytemp - collisionHeight/2) / map.getTileSize());
        Point bottomRight = new Point(((int)(xtemp + dx) + collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize(), ((int)ytemp + collisionHeight/2) / map.getTileSize());

        // Left
        if(dx < 0)
        {
            boolean collision = false;
            for(int row = topLeft.y; row <= bottomRight.y; row++)
            {
                if(map.getType(row, topLeft.x) == Tile.SOLID) 
                { 
                    collision = true; 
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(collision)
            {
                dx = 0;

                // Move player to edge of solid tile
                int col = ((int)(xtemp + dx) - collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize();
                xtemp = col * map.getTileSize() + collisionWidth / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                xtemp += dx;
            }
        }

        // Right
        if(dx > 0)
        {
            boolean collision = false;
            for(int row = topLeft.y; row <= bottomRight.y; row++)
            {
                if(map.getType(row, bottomRight.x) == Tile.SOLID) 
                { 
                    collision = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(collision)
            {
                dx = 0;

                // Move player to edge of solid tile
                int col = ((int)(xtemp + dx) + collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize();
                xtemp = (col + 1) * map.getTileSize() - collisionWidth / 2 - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                xtemp += dx;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You have some code duplication there

  > ```
  > for(int row = topLeft.y; row <= bottomRight.y; row++)
  > {
  >     if(map.getType(row, topLeft.x) == Tile.SOLID) 
  >     { 
  >         collision = true; 
  >         break;
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

  which should be extracted to a method like

  ```
  private boolean hasCollision(int start, int stop, int x){

      for(int row = start; row <= stop; row++)
      {
          if(map.getType(row, x) == Tile.SOLID) 
          { 
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
   }
  ```
- If a collision is found you have this

  > ```
  > dx = 0;
  >
  > // Move player to edge of solid tile
  > int col = ((int)(xtemp + dx) - collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize();
  > ```

  Do you on purpose set `dx = 0` and calling then `(xtemp + dx)` ?
- You are also doing a lot of `collisionWidth/2` which should be extracted to a variable.
- you should extract the `left` and `right` checking to separate methods.
- in Java the convention is to place the opening brace `{` on the same line.
- using a guard clause for `dx == 0` well remove the creation of the `Point`'s
- comments should describe **why** something is done. **What is done should be described by the code itself by using meaningful names.

Implementing most the points above leads to

```
// Corrects X movement if a collision occurs.
private void checkXCollision()
{
    if (dx == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Point topLeft = new Point(((int)(xtemp + dx) - collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize(), ((int)ytemp - collisionHeight/2) / map.getTileSize());
    Point bottomRight = new Point(((int)(xtemp + dx) + collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize(), ((int)ytemp + collisionHeight/2) / map.getTileSize());

    if(dx < 0){

        checkLeftXCollision(topLeft, bottomRight);

    } else {

        checkRightXCollision(topLeft, bottomRight);

    }
}

private void checkLeftXCollision(Point topLeft, Point bottomRight) {

    if(hasCollision(topLeft.y, bottomRight.y, topLeft.x)) {
        dx = 0;

        int col = ((int)(xtemp + dx) - collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize();
        xtemp = col * map.getTileSize() + collisionWidth / 2;
    } else {
        xtemp += dx;
    }
}

private void checkRightXCollision(Point topLeft, Point bottomRight) {

    if(hasCollision(topLeft.y, bottomRight.y, bottomRight.x)) {
        dx = 0;

        int col = ((int)(xtemp + dx) + collisionWidth/2) / map.getTileSize();
        xtemp = (col + 1) * map.getTileSize() - collisionWidth / 2 - 1;
    } else {
        xtemp += dx;
    }
}    

private boolean hasCollision(int start, int stop, int x){

    for(int row = start; row <= stop; row++)
    {
        if(map.getType(row, x) == Tile.SOLID) 
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```